# Jenkins - execute script on different machine with local env variables

Tags: java, bash, shell, jenkins, groovy

Have:

1. Jenkins job that needs to execute bash command and initialise variable locally:

   GOOD_VARIABLE=`command`
2. SSH into remote host and execute another command with above variable

   `command ${GOOD_VARIABLE}...`

Problem:

I know how to ssh into another machine and execute command there but how can I pass that ***local*** variable to remote host?

Tried but didn't work:

- Pre build script
- Inject environment variables to the build process

Comment: See e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/163167/when-sshing-how-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-server-that-changes-f Does that help?

Answer (score -1):

sounds like your problem is how to send a var through SSH.

You have a detailed answer there:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299037/pass-variable-in-ssh

Don't forget the -T when using SSH through Jenkins!

Comment: the answer does not provide a solution